# Pressure vs Volume Calculation for air

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, air, volume

I have 1 litre of air in a sealed container at atmosphere pressure (approx 15 psi absolute).
I want to reduce pressure in the container by 1 psi ( 14 psi absolute or -1 psig).

- If I understand correctly that 1 psi reduction is 6.66 % reduction in pressure compared to standard atmospheric pressure,
- Applying the same to volume would it be correct to say that
  if I increase the volume of the container by 6.66 %  the pressure would drop by 1psi for air OR
- If i remove 6.66% volume of air in the container I would still be able to achieve the 1psi drop in pressure?

Do some other factors come in to play for pressure / volume calculation...?

Comment: An alternative way to do this (other than using intuition as you're doing) would be to use the ideal gas law.

Comment: @BMS and how do I do that? are you referring to PV = nRT ?

Comment: Your textbook will have examples. Yes, I'm referring to $PV=nRT$.

Comment: Even simpler, if pressure and temperature are the only variables (everything else remaining constant), $P_1V_1 = P_2V_2$

Comment: @DaveCoffman That is exactly the same thing.

Comment: You need the volume to become 15/14 liter to get pressure to go from 15 to 14, assuming temperature of gas is kept constant. If you have a diabetic expansion (work done during expansion but no heat flows into the cylinder to restore the temperature) then you need to know more about your gas (specifically the ratio of heat capacity at constant volume vs at constant pressure) in order to do the calculation.

Comment: @Floris you mean "adiabatic", I think

Comment: @DaveCoffman yes I did mean adiabatic and didn't notice auto"correct"

Answer (score 1):

Answer to question (1) is NO: 
Using the equations of the comments $(P_1 V_1=P_2 V_2$), you get:
$P_2=P_1/(1+.06666)$ (in this case of a small drop in pressure the answer will be approximately correct though, because $1/(1+x) \simeq 1-x$ for $x<<1$)

Answer to question (2) is YES: 
Using $n_2RT_1=(1-0.06666)n_1RT_1$ you get $P_2=(1-.0666)P_1$

Comment: Shouldn't Boyles law be applicable in this case `product of pressure and volume is a constant for a given mass of confined gas as long as the temperature is constant`

Comment: sure, I used it in the first question, but in the second one you remove air, so you no longer have a "given mass of confined gas" (I assumed you took out, that is let 0.0666 of the mass of the gas escape). If that not was the case, could you please clarify the question?

Comment: so if I allow 66ml of air to escape shouldn't it be the same as the first case. the pressure inside the container should drop by 1psi??

Comment: first, if you understand the math, which I now doubt, in the first case, when you keep the same amount of gas and increase the volume, the result is only approximate.  In the second case you do get the result you want, but not because of Boyle's law, because you no longer have the same amount of gas.

Comment: is this homework? are you in high or middle school? I am asking just to know at what level we can communicate to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The idea gas law work; more specifically Boyle's law is a reciprocal law. Pressure and volume are inversely related. When you increase volume by a factor of 1.0666 (by 6.66%), you decrease pressure by $\frac{1}{1.0666}$.

Pressure is inversely proportional to volume.

$P \propto \frac{1}{V}$

So when you increase pressure by a certain factor, volume decreases by the reciprocal of the factor. 
Of course as user16007 said for very small factors, it does approximate to the what you said in your second bullet point.